# Calculating year over year growth by group in Pandas

Tags: python, function, indexing, pandas

I have the following `dataframe`:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 

ID            Month           Transaction_Amount

1             2013/01         10
1             2013/02         20
1             2013/03         10
1             2013/04         20
1             2013/05         10
1             2013/06         20
1             2013/07         10
1             2013/08         20
1             2013/09         10
1             2013/10         20
1             2013/11         10
1             2013/12         20
1             2014/01         15
1             2014/02         25
1             2014/03         15
1             2014/04         25
...
1             2014/11         15
1             2014/12         25
...
10000000      2014/11         13
10000000      2014/12         23
```

What I would like to do is calculate the growth over rolling month periods year over year, so for example, I would want to find the value of `(2014/01 - 2013/01) / (2014/01)` which is `(15 - 10) / (15) = 1/3` and save this for the first rolling period.  There will be a total of 12 rolling periods for each `ID`.  I'm thinking that the final output should look like:

```
In [2]: df_new
Out[2]: 

ID       rolling_period_1   rolling_period_2  ... rolling_period_12

1        .333333            .25                   .25
2        x1                 x2                    x12
3        y1                 y2                    y12
4        z1                 z2                    z12
...
```

I generated a list containing tuples of every year over period `[(2013/01, 2014/01), (2013/02, 2014/02) ... (2013/12, 2014/12)]` and have been playing around with `isin` to index a subset of the original `df`, but I am unsure how to arrive at the `df_new`.

**EDIT**

I have created a new dataframe called `temp_df` with the following code:

```
In [4]: temp_df = df[df['month'].isin(('2013/01','2014/01'))]

In [5]: temp_df
Out[5]:

ID            Month           Transaction_Amount

1             2013/01         10
1             2014/01         15
2             2013/01         20
2             2014/01         30
3             2013/01         15
3             2014/01         30
...
```

What I would like to produce is a `DataFrame` that looks like the following:

```
In [6]: new_df
Out[6]:

ID            Transaction_Growth

1             .3333   # (15-10)/15
2             .3333   # (30-20)/30
3             .50     # (30-15)/30
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use shift to offset the rows in the dataframe.

Create dummy data with month column and values column

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=90, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':range(1,91),'date':rng})
```

set the month column to index

```
df = df.set_index('date')
```

shift a copy of the dataframe 12 periods to get the value 12 months ago, minus from the current record, and divide by current record:

```
df - df.shift(12)/ df
```

*update the sign on the period in the shift function*

**Updated to consider ID**

```
# Create range of months
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=180, freq='M')
ID = np.array([1,2,3])

# Create ID column
ID = np.repeat(ID,60)

# Create dummy data in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':ID,'value':range(1,181),'date':rng})

# Use shift on a group by object
(df.value - df.groupby(['ID']).value.shift(12))/ df.value
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing or why you're doing it.  Why do I want to offset the rows in the dataframe?

Comment: to calculate this: (2014/01 - 2013/01) / (2014/01)

Comment: edited to explain more clearly. Perhaps I misunderstand the requirements

Comment: Why are you creating the `rng` datetime?  Also, how does this account for the fact that I have many different `ID`s?

Comment: I am creating the rng to use as the data column. It is not clear from your question how the ids should be used. If you want get the yearly growth per month per id, then you can group by id.

Answer (score 17):

I think there is a much more simple way to do this that doesn't require keeping track of shifting time periods, try using the `df.pct_change()` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date_range = pd.period_range("2016-01", "2018-01",freq='m')
df= pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(len(date_range))}, index=date_range)
df['pct_pop'] = df['A'].pct_change()
df['pct_yoy'] = df['A'].pct_change(12)
df

               A    pct_pop     pct_yoy
2016-01 0.478381    NaN NaN
2016-02 0.941450    0.967991    NaN
2016-03 0.128445    -0.863567   NaN
2016-04 0.498623    2.882011    NaN
2016-05 0.914663    0.834377    NaN
2016-06 0.349565    -0.617821   NaN
2016-07 0.563296    0.611419    NaN
2016-08 0.144055    -0.744264   NaN
2016-09 0.502279    2.486708    NaN
2016-10 0.621283    0.236928    NaN
2016-11 0.716813    0.153763    NaN
2016-12 0.152372    -0.787431   NaN
2017-01 0.160636    0.054234    -0.664209
2017-02 0.496759    2.092453    -0.472347
2017-03 0.324318    -0.347132   1.524965
2017-04 0.431651    0.330949    -0.134315
2017-05 0.973095    1.254357    0.063884
2017-06 0.007917    -0.991864   -0.977351
2017-07 0.875365    109.562870  0.554005
2017-08 0.860987    -0.016425   4.976784
2017-09 0.099549    -0.884378   -0.801805
2017-10 0.544275    4.467398    -0.123950
2017-11 0.433326    -0.203846   -0.395482
2017-12 0.688057    0.587850    3.515636
2018-01 0.924038    0.342967    4.752374
```