# Year On Year Growth Using Pandas - Traverse N rows Back

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a lot of parameters on which I have to calculate the year on year growth.

```
Type                    2006-Q1 2006-Q2 2006-Q3 2006-Q4 2007-Q1 2007-Q2 2007-Q3 2007-Q4 2008-Q1 2008-Q2 2008-Q3 2008-Q4
MonMkt_IntRt            3.44    3.60    3.99    4.40    4.61    4.73    5.11    4.97    4.92    4.89    5.29    4.51
RtlVol                  97.08   97.94   98.25   99.15   99.63   100.29  100.71  101.18  102.04  101.56  101.05  99.49
IntRt                   4.44    5.60    6.99    7.40    8.61    9.73    9.11    9.97    9.92    9.89    7.29    9.51
GMR                     9.08    9.94    9.25    9.15    9.63    10.29   10.71   10.18   10.04   10.56   10.05   9.49
```

I need to calculate the growth, i.e in column 2007-Q1 i need to find the growth from 2006-Q1. The formula is (2007-Q1/2006-Q1) - 1

I have gone through the link below and tried to code 
[Calculating year over year growth by group in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328636/calculating-year-over-year-growth-by-group-in-pandas)

```
df = pd.read_csv('c:/Econometric/EconoModel.csv')
df.set_index('Type',inplace=True)
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
df_t = df.T
df_output=(df_cd_americas_t/df_cd_americas_t.shift(4)) -1
```

The output is as below

```
Type                    2006-Q1 2006-Q2 2006-Q3 2006-Q4 2007-Q1 2007-Q2 2007-Q3 2007-Q4 2008-Q1 2008-Q2 2008-Q3 2008-Q4
MonMkt_IntRt                                            0.3398  0.3159  0.2806  0.1285  0.0661  0.0340  0.0363  -0.0912
RtlVol                                                  0.0261  0.0240  0.0249  0.0204  0.0242  0.0126  0.0033  -0.0166
IntRt                                                   0.6666  0.5375  0.3919  0.2310  0.1579  0.0195  0.0856  -0.2688
GMR                                                     0.0077  -0.031  0.1124  0.1704  0.0571  -0.024  -0.014  -0.0127
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iloc to shift data slices. See an example on test df.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({i:[0+i,1+i,2+i] for i in range(0,12)})
print(df)
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13


df.iloc[:,list(range(3,12))] = df.iloc[:,list(range(3,12))].values/ df.iloc[:,list(range(0,9))].values - 1
print(df)
    0   1   2  3    4    5     6     7     8         9         10   
0   0   1   2  inf  3.0  1.50  1.00  0.75  0.600000  0.500000  0.428571   
1   1   2   3  3.0  1.5  1.00  0.75  0.60  0.500000  0.428571  0.375000   
2   2   3   4  1.5  1.0  0.75  0.60  0.50  0.428571  0.375000  0.333333   

   11  
0  0.375000  
1  0.333333  
2  0.300000
```

Comment: Hi , I am getting the below error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'unicode'"

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any issue with your code.
Simply added **axis=1** to the *dataframe.shift()* method as you are trying to do the **column comparison**
I have executed the following code it is giving the result you expected.

> ```
> def getSampleDataframe():
>     df_economy_model = pd.DataFrame(
>         {
>         'Type':['MonMkt_IntRt', 'RtlVol', 'IntRt', 'GMR'],
>         '2006-Q1':[3.44, 97.08, 4.44, 9.08],
>         '2006-Q2':[3.6, 97.94, 5.6, 9.94],
>         '2006-Q3':[3.99, 98.25, 6.99, 9.25],
>         '2006-Q4':[4.4, 99.15, 7.4, 9.15],
>         '2007-Q1':[4.61, 99.63, 8.61, 9.63],
>         '2007-Q2':[4.73, 100.29, 9.73, 10.29],
>         '2007-Q3':[5.11, 100.71, 9.11, 10.71],
>         '2007-Q4':[4.97, 101.18, 9.97, 10.18],
>         '2008-Q1':[4.92, 102.04, 9.92, 10.04],
>         '2008-Q2':[4.89, 101.56, 9.89, 10.56],
>         '2008-Q3':[5.29, 101.05, 7.29, 10.05],
>         '2008-Q4':[4.51, 99.49, 9.51, 9.49]
>         })  # Your data
>     return df_economy_model> 
>
> df_cd_americas = getSampleDataframe()
> df_cd_americas.set_index('Type', inplace=True)
> df_yearly_growth = (df/df.shift(4, axis=1))-1
> print (df_cd_americas)
> print (df_yearly_growth)
> ```

Comment: Hi , I am getting the below error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'unicode'"

Comment: Print the dataframe. Looks like one of the columns is a string non-numeric. Probably 'Type' or quarter names are part of data. Division operator is unable to handle strings. I have tested with the dataframe returned by 'getSampleDataframe()', it worked fine. Just print the dataframe you are using yourself will be clear why this error is coming.

Comment: Yes thanks. I got those columns and converted them to float and then applied the functions.